# How to allow download resuming but prevent segmented downloading?

Tags: php, http, download, resume-download

I have a php script which generates a file to be downloaded.
I added all the necessary stuff and byte serving is working very well. You can pause and resume, use tools that download multiple segments of the file to maximize speed and such.

However, I would like to prevent people from using such tools. All I want is for them to have the ability to resume the download (in case of internet loss, power surge, the need to pause it, ...) but not to make multiple requests for different pieces of the same file.

What would be the best way to do that ?

Can I simply send a 416 Range Not Satisfiable if the end range isn't the last byte of the file ? Or should I send a 429 Too Many Requests ?